# Order array by values inside it's objects and date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array like this:

```
[{
Animal:{Tag:1, Eats:"Grass"},
Color:{Id:1, ColorName: "Black",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T13:45:00"
},
{
Animal:{Tag:2, Eats:"Meat"},
Color:{Id:2, ColorName: "Brown",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-07T13:45:00"
},
{
Animal:{Tag:3, Eats:"Water"},
Color:{Id:3, ColorName: "White",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T11:45:00"
},
{
Animal:{Tag:4, Eats:"Grass"},
Color:{Id:4, ColorName: "Yellow",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T14:45:00"
}]
```

I want to order it in such way that it is first ordered by "Eats" and within them it should be ordered by "DateAndTime". So, ideally it should return like this:

```
[{
Animal:{Tag:1, Eats:"Grass"},
Color:{Id:1, ColorName: "Black",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T13:45:00"
}
,
{
Animal:{Tag:4, Eats:"Grass"},
Color:{Id:4, ColorName: "Yellow",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T14:45:00"
},
{
Animal:{Tag:3, Eats:"Meat"},
Color:{Id:3, ColorName: "White",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T11:45:00"
},
{
Animal:{Tag:2, Eats:"Meat"},
Color:{Id:2, ColorName: "Brown",
DateAndTime:"2019-06-07T13:45:00"
}]
```

Using lodash I was able to order it by the DateAndTime but I couldn't order it by "Eats" first. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string#localeCompare` to sort the array first on the `Eats` fields and then on the `DateAndTime` field.

```js
let data = [{ Animal:{Tag:1, Eats:"Grass"}, Color:{Id:1, ColorName: "Black"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T13:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:2, Eats:"Meat"}, Color:{Id:2, ColorName: "Brown"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-07T13:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:3, Eats:"Water"}, Color:{Id:3, ColorName:"White"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T11:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:4, Eats:"Grass"}, Color:{Id:4, ColorName: "Yellow"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T14:45:00" }];
data.sort((a,b) => a.Animal.Eats.localeCompare(b.Animal.Eats) || a.DateAndTime.localeCompare(b.DateAndTime));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

You can use `lodash#sortBy` to sort the data.

```js
let data = [{ Animal:{Tag:1, Eats:"Grass"}, Color:{Id:1, ColorName: "Black"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T13:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:2, Eats:"Meat"}, Color:{Id:2, ColorName: "Brown"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-07T13:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:3, Eats:"Water"}, Color:{Id:3, ColorName:"White"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T11:45:00" }, { Animal:{Tag:4, Eats:"Grass"}, Color:{Id:4, ColorName: "Yellow"}, DateAndTime:"2019-06-06T14:45:00" }],
    result = _.sortBy(data, ['Animal.Eats', 'DateAndTime']);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```